# Some doubts related to Lovasz Local Lemma.

Tags: probability, asymptotics, probabilistic-method

I have 2 question regarding Lovasz Local Lemma.

1. In the book [Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521835402) 
    , it is shown that $Pr(\cap_{i=1}^n \overline{E_i}) \ge (1-2p)^n $ while proving Lovasz Local Lemma(Symmetric case). If $p=1/2$ ,then this expression is not strictly greater than 0, hence there is finite chance that some of the "bad" events might occur. Should this condition not be specified beforehand.
2. $e(m(m-1)+1)k(1-\frac{1}{k})^m \le 1$ then $m > (3+o(1))k\log k$. How to prove this? Here $e$ is the base of natural logarithm, and m,k are positive integers.

Comment: The first question is highly specific and it would be easier to find someone who can answer if you can provide more details from the book.  For the second question, it looks incorrect without more context: what is $n$?

Comment: I have edited the 2nd question. As for the first question, I am working on a latex proof .

Comment: @SudipitaRoy For 2), the idea is to first show that $m > k$ (that's the point of the factor of $e$), then it means that the $e(m(m-1)+1)k$ factor is at least $\Omega(k^3)$.  Now work out how big $m$ has to be to make the cofactor $(1-\tfrac1k)^m$ smaller than $O(1/k^3)$.

Comment: For 1), can you at least *state* the version of LLL that is being proven?  In most formulations I know of, $p$ will be much smaller than $1/2$ by the conditions of the theorem.  Which leads me to suspect you are talking about a very specific low-degree case.